create new variable with ordered numerical codes
I have the following dataset:
group   id  date
G1      A   12/10/2007
G1      A   13/10/2007
G1      A   14/10/2007
G1      B   15/10/2007
G1      B   16/10/2007
G1      A   17/10/2007
G2      A   25/10/2007
G2      A   26/10/2007
G2      C   27/10/2007
G2      B   28/10/2007
G2      B   29/10/2007
G2      A   30/10/2007

And I want to add a new column that converts the ID to a numeric, ordered form (starting from 1), by group. The order should be by date (which, in this case, is already ordered). The output would look like this:
group   id  date        id_new
G1      A   12/10/2007  1
G1      A   13/10/2007  1
G1      A   14/10/2007  1
G1      B   15/10/2007  2
G1      B   16/10/2007  2
G1      A   17/10/2007  1
G2      A   25/10/2007  1
G2      A   26/10/2007  1
G2      C   27/10/2007  2
G2      B   28/10/2007  3
G2      B   29/10/2007  3
G2      A   30/10/2007  1

So, it's ok that individual A (or another) is, in one group, "1", and in another group is "2"; I just need to have the id_new coded by first arrival (date). I suppose this can be done with dplyr but not sure how...? I would use group_by(group) for sure, but not sure which function to use after.
Dataset for reproducing the example:
structure(c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G2", 
"G2", "G2", "G2", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
"B", "B", "A", "12/10/2007", "13/10/2007", "14/10/2007", "15/10/2007", 
"16/10/2007", "17/10/2007", "25/10/2007", "26/10/2007", "27/10/2007", 
"28/10/2007", "29/10/2007", "30/10/2007", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "1"), dim = c(12L, 4L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("group", "id", "date", "id_new")))


You can use the forcats package to convert id to a factor and then to integer.
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id_new = as.integer(forcats::fct_inorder(as.factor(id))))

# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group id    date       id_new
   <chr> <chr> <chr>       <int>
 1 G1    A     12/10/2007      1
 2 G1    A     13/10/2007      1
 3 G1    A     14/10/2007      1
 4 G1    B     15/10/2007      2
 5 G1    B     16/10/2007      2
 6 G1    A     17/10/2007      1
 7 G2    A     25/10/2007      1
 8 G2    A     26/10/2007      1
 9 G2    C     27/10/2007      2
10 G2    B     28/10/2007      3
11 G2    B     29/10/2007      3
12 G2    A     30/10/2007      1


This works well, thanks! Maybe just correct the package, I think it should be "forcats"

You can try converting the id column to a factor, and then convert the result to numeric, which takes the levels of the factor. This doesn't work, since you want the id numbers to run sequentially based on the date as shown here.
as.data.frame(df) |>
   mutate(id_new2=as.numeric(factor(id)), .by=group)


   group id       date id_new id_new2
1     G1  A 12/10/2007      1       1
2     G1  A 13/10/2007      1       1
3     G1  A 14/10/2007      1       1
4     G1  B 15/10/2007      2       2
5     G1  B 16/10/2007      2       2
6     G1  A 17/10/2007      1       1
7     G2  A 25/10/2007      1       1
8     G2  A 26/10/2007      1       1
9     G2  C 27/10/2007      2       3
10    G2  B 28/10/2007      3       2
11    G2  B 29/10/2007      3       2
12    G2  A 30/10/2007      1       1

A workaround is to use forcats fct_reorder function to sort the levels of the factor based on the date:
as.data.frame(df) |>
  mutate(date=as.Date(date, format="%d/%m/%Y"), 
         id_new2=as.numeric(fct_reorder(id, date)), .by=group)


   group id       date id_new id_new2
1     G1  A 12/10/2007      1       1
2     G1  A 13/10/2007      1       1
3     G1  A 14/10/2007      1       1
4     G1  B 15/10/2007      2       2
5     G1  B 16/10/2007      2       2
6     G1  A 17/10/2007      1       1
7     G2  A 25/10/2007      1       1
8     G2  A 26/10/2007      1       1
9     G2  C 27/10/2007      2       2
10    G2  B 28/10/2007      3       3
11    G2  B 29/10/2007      3       3
12    G2  A 30/10/2007      1       1


a data.table approach
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[mydata[, .SD[, .GRP, id], group], new_id := i.GRP, on = .(group, id)]

#     group     id       date new_id
#    <char> <char>     <char>  <int>
# 1:     G1      A 12/10/2007      1
# 2:     G1      A 13/10/2007      1
# 3:     G1      A 14/10/2007      1
# 4:     G1      B 15/10/2007      2
# 5:     G1      B 16/10/2007      2
# 6:     G1      A 17/10/2007      1
# 7:     G2      A 25/10/2007      1
# 8:     G2      A 26/10/2007      1
# 9:     G2      C 27/10/2007      2
#10:     G2      B 28/10/2007      3
#11:     G2      B 29/10/2007      3
#12:     G2      A 30/10/2007      1

explanation:
mydata[, .SD[, .GRP, id], group]
#     group     id   GRP
#    <char> <char> <int>
# 1:     G1      A     1
# 2:     G1      B     2
# 3:     G2      A     1
# 4:     G2      C     2
# 5:     G2      B     3

creates a temporary lookup table, on which you can perform a join by reference to obtain the wanted value of new_id

Sometimes, specially if you have multiple groups or complex conditions, maybe want to complete/expand cases, edit labels, make adjustments in general or build a new df "from scratch", is nice to have a dedicated table for ids/labels and join it later.
With this on mind, here's the take:
(Toy data at the end)
library(tidyverse)

# The helper. Edit, filter or use to start a new df. 
my_ids <- my_df %>% 
  distinct(group, id) %>% 
  mutate(.by = group, this_id = row_number())

> my_ids
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  group id    this_id
  <chr> <chr>   <int>
1 G1    A           1
2 G1    B           2
3 G2    A           1
4 G2    C           2
5 G2    B           3

# After your data wrangling, just join it.
my_df  <- left_join(my_df, my_ids, by = c("group", "id"))

The output:
> my_df
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   group id    date       id_new this_id
   <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <int>
 1 G1    A     12/10/2007 1            1
 2 G1    A     13/10/2007 1            1
 3 G1    A     14/10/2007 1            1
 4 G1    B     15/10/2007 2            2
 5 G1    B     16/10/2007 2            2
 6 G1    A     17/10/2007 1            1
 7 G2    A     25/10/2007 1            1
 8 G2    A     26/10/2007 1            1
 9 G2    C     27/10/2007 2            2
10 G2    B     28/10/2007 3            3
11 G2    B     29/10/2007 3            3
12 G2    A     30/10/2007 1            1

Toy data:
# Toy data (as tibble/df, if you want to use `dplyr`)
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~id,        ~date, ~id_new,
  "G1", "A", "12/10/2007",     "1",
  "G1", "A", "13/10/2007",     "1",
  "G1", "A", "14/10/2007",     "1",
  "G1", "B", "15/10/2007",     "2",
  "G1", "B", "16/10/2007",     "2",
  "G1", "A", "17/10/2007",     "1",
  "G2", "A", "25/10/2007",     "1",
  "G2", "A", "26/10/2007",     "1",
  "G2", "C", "27/10/2007",     "2",
  "G2", "B", "28/10/2007",     "3",
  "G2", "B", "29/10/2007",     "3",
  "G2", "A", "30/10/2007",     "1")

Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0
